# remove elements from structure

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

I have the following code which is working fine except that when an element is removed, it is removed from parental structure. I need the parental structure (first_name) to remain intact with all elements:

```
struct names_list {
    char username[20];
    struct names_list * next;
};
pthread_mutex_t name_list;

int retu = 0;
char username[20];
struct names_list * curr_name = first_name;
struct names_list * temp_name = NULL;
while( curr_name != NULL )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&name_list);
    strncpy(username, curr_name->username, sizeof( username ) - 1 );
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&name_list);
    //validate
    retu = validate_name(sock,buff,sizeof(buff),username,domain);
    switch ( retu )
    {
    case 0:
        pthread_mutex_lock(&name_list);
        if (temp_name == NULL)
             first_name = curr_name->next;  //this is used for removing when current is first record
        else
            temp_name->next = curr_name->next; //this is used for removing current record from mid-list

        free(curr_name);//Freeing should be needed
        curr_name = curr_name->next;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&name_list);
        break;

    case 1:
        pthread_mutex_lock(&name_list);
        temp_name = curr_name;
        curr_name = curr_name->next;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&name_list);
        break;
    }

    if (retu == 2)
        break;
}

pthread_mutex_lock(&name_list);
curr_name = first_name;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&name_list);
```

***How can I remove element only from curr_name and keep the original structure in first_name ?***

Comment: `curr_name = curr_name->next;` immediately after `free(curr_name);` is undefined behaviour. Apart from that, what is `first_name`, and what does `validate_name` do?

Comment: validate_name returns 0 or 1 and it's not relevant for this question. my problem is related to structures and how to handle them as I posted

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "keep the original structure in the first_name" do you want the Head of the remaining items after the remove to be pointed to by first_name?

Comment: If `validate_name` returns 0, then the current list element should be deleted, is that right? And, once again, what is `first_name`? A global, a function argument, or what?

Comment: I need the first_name structure with all the elements and from the other one (curr_name) which is a copy of first_name to remove invalid names. So in the end I need a structure containing all elements(first_name) and one containg valid ones(curr_name). Right now the code removes the invalid element from first_name and it's wrong

Comment: first_name is the structure containing all elements. I didn't post the part where the records are loaded into first_name struct.

Comment: curr_name is not a copy of first name's elements. it points to the same first element as first_name, so you are modifying the original list. you need to create a new list if you want to maintain 2 distinct lists that point to different items. I'll post a solution is a bit.

Comment: Wait. `first_name` appears to be a `struct names_list*`. Probably the first element of a linked list. And you want to keep all names in that list, but delete invalid ones, too? You need to copy the list then.

Comment: yes, I need the original list and remove the invalid ones from its copy which I will use on other function later. If you have a solution please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution.

```
struct names_list {
        char username[20];
        struct names_list * next;
};
pthread_mutex_t name_list;


int retu = 0;
char username[20];
struct names_list * temp_list_head=NULL;
struct names_list * prev_list_node=NULL;
struct names_list * curr_name = first_name;
struct names_list * temp_name = NULL;

//make a copy of your list
while (curr_name){
    struct names_list *tempNode = malloc(sizeof( struct names_list));
    *tempNode = *curr_name;
    if (temp_list_head== NULL)
        temp_list_head = tempNode;
    if (prev_list_node!=NULL)
        prev_list_node->next = tempNode;
    prev_list_node = tempNode;
    curr_name = curr_name->next;
}

curr_name = temp_list_head;

while( curr_name != NULL )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&name_list);
    strncpy(username, curr_name->username, sizeof( username ) - 1 );
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&name_list);
    //validate
    retu = validate_name(sock,buff,sizeof(buff),username,domain);
    switch ( retu )
    {
       case 0:
         pthread_mutex_lock(&name_list);
         if (temp_name == NULL)
              temp_list_head = curr_name->next;  //this is used for removing when current is first record
         else
              temp_name->next = curr_name->next; //this is used for removing current record from mid-list
         free(curr_name);//Freeing should be needed
        // curr_name = curr_name->next; //not needed, its removed from the list
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&name_list);
         break;
       case 1:
         pthread_mutex_lock(&name_list);
         temp_name = curr_name;
         curr_name = curr_name->next;
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&name_list);
         break;
    }
    if (retu == 2)
         break;
}
pthread_mutex_lock(&name_list);
curr_name = temp_list_head;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&name_list);
```

Comment: It's C, no `new` here, must be `malloc`. And the `memcpy` should use `sizeof *curr_name`, but why not just `*temp_node = *curr_name`?

Comment: good call on the C thing, brains asleep. As for the memcpy, you want the size of the structure don't you? So it should be of the struct. *curr_name will be the same thing, but less obvious since you should use types with sizeof. and you are right, assigning the memory is much more succinct using the = operator. edited as such. Thanks!

Comment: will this affect the speed or memory used ? I used malloc to add records to first_name structure. Is there any other way to make a copy of the structure without using malloc ?

Comment: Yes it will effect performance. no there is no way around it. You need dedicated memory for the new list, so you'll need to allocate it. As far as performance of allocating itself, you could optimize it if you wanted to implement a slab or pool allocator. thats a whole different issue, however. I would consider the circumstances of this program, and whether or not X many calls to malloc will greatly affect performance of the application as a whole.

Comment: You originally had `sizeof(curr_name)` in the `memcpy`, which is the size of the pointer, not of the struct. Typo, I suppose.

Comment: I see, ya sorry about that

Comment: I get an error at this line: names_list *tempNode = malloc(sizeof(names_list)); .... it says: test.c:123: error: `names_list' undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:123: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:123: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:123: error: `tempNode' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: o and malloc(sizeof(struct names_list));